# Running .jad file in Mac OSX Lion

Tags: java, macos, java-me

I want to run a .jad file in Mac OSX Lion. I tried with WTK 2.5.2 linux edition on mac and got the below error.

```
:bin$ ./emulator -Xdescriptor my-jadfile.jad
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Applications/WTK2.5.2/bin/sublime.so:  no suitable image found. 
    Did find:  /Applications/WTK2.5.2/bin/sublime.so:
    unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1827)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1703)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:770)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1020)
    at com.sun.kvem.Sublime.(Sublime.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at com.sun.kvem.Lime.createLime(Lime.java:40)
    at com.sun.kvem.KVMBridge.(KVMBridge.java:46)
    at com.sun.kvem.KVMBridge.getBridge(KVMBridge.java:37)
    at com.sun.kvem.midp.MIDP.run(MIDP.java:699)
    at com.sun.kvem.environment.EmulatorInvoker.runEmulatorImpl(EmulatorInvoker.java:107)
    at com.sun.kvem.environment.EmulatorInvoker.main(EmulatorInvoker.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.kvem.environment.JVM.main(JVM.java:103)
```

I tired with WTK3 but it does not give an option to run the .jad files directly. Any help on this please.

I have also tried with an emulator called "mpowerplayer", it is able to run the .jad but there is a different issue. I have a date field in the form which is not getting enabled in the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to run it on JME SDK 3 by executing the emulator under bin directory. For me it was in "/Applications/Java_ME_SDK_3.0.app/Contents/Resources/bin".

Answer (score 2):

The library you're trying to load (sublime.so) is an ELF library, probably for Linux. It cannot be loaded on OS X.