# PI4J - Unable to load [libpi4j.so] using path

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, raspberry-pi, pi4j

I'm using NetBeans on MacOS to develop an application using PI4J. Everything looks Ok but I get the error below, saying that PI4J was unable to load. Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
abr 18, 2015 3:02:30 PM com.pi4j.util.NativeLibraryLoader load
SEVERE: Unable to load [libpi4j.so] using path: [/lib/libpi4j.so]
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/0x/6rph2scs0f544b7xwkfhzkcw0000gn/T/libpi4j3968879292977354112.so: dlopen(/private/var/folders/0x/6rph2scs0f544b7xwkfhzkcw0000gn/T/libpi4j3968879292977354112.so, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/folders/0x/6rph2scs0f544b7xwkfhzkcw0000gn/T/libpi4j3968879292977354112.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1822)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.pi4j.util.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryFromClasspath(NativeLibraryLoader.java:143)
    at com.pi4j.util.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:92)
    at com.pi4j.wiringpi.Gpio.<clinit>(Gpio.java:174)
    at com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiGpioProvider.<init>(RaspiGpioProvider.java:51)
    at com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory.getDefaultProvider(GpioFactory.java:106)
    at com.pi4j.io.gpio.impl.GpioControllerImpl.<init>(GpioControllerImpl.java:54)
    at com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory.getInstance(GpioFactory.java:89)
    at hellorasp.HelloRasp.main(HelloRasp.java:31)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.pi4j.wiringpi.Gpio.wiringPiSetup()I
    at com.pi4j.wiringpi.Gpio.wiringPiSetup(Native Method)
    at com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiGpioProvider.<init>(RaspiGpioProvider.java:51)
    at com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory.getDefaultProvider(GpioFactory.java:106)
    at com.pi4j.io.gpio.impl.GpioControllerImpl.<init>(GpioControllerImpl.java:54)
    at com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory.getInstance(GpioFactory.java:89)
    at hellorasp.HelloRasp.main(HelloRasp.java:31)
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832862/running-jad-file-in-mac-osx-lion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get remove wiringpi -y
sudo apt-get --yes install git-core gcc make
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi --branch master --single-branch wiringpi
cd ~/wiringpi
sudo ./build
```

This is taken from pi4j
I faced this issue and when I executed these lines in terminal...everything worked perfectly

Comment: The official WiringPi project was deprecated and lacks support for the Raspberry Pi 4/400/CM4. A fork is available on GitHub in the repo mentioned in this answer, with some improvements to fix this. More info is available on https://pi4j.com/1.4/dependency.html

Answer (score 1):

/lib/libpi4j.so file will not work because it is tailored just for Raspberry Pi, not any other hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue working with Raspberry P4, java 11 and pi4j v2.
I solved it downloading pigpio library directly from the raspberry

```
sudo apt-get install pigpio
```

After the library was installed, the jar worked perfecrly

Comment: It seems we are missing some documentation on the Pi4J website regarding the need to install pigpio itself as this only needs to be done in certain cases. I would like to understand your approach Roberto, what steps you took, etc. so I can extend the documentation. Would be great if you could share here or via https://github.com/Pi4J/pi4j-v2/discussions

Answer (score -1):

just copy libpi4j.so to your project lib folder on RPI

Answer (score -1):

assuming the OP is running his code on a raspberry pi, I also got this error on a pi running code that controlled servos that worked as of Feb-2018 but produced this exact error in Jul-2018.  I found a change in the pi4j 1.2 distro needs you to install the wiringpi library manually

so i got that exact error, followed these instructions and my servos are moving again:

http://wiringpi.com/download-and-install/